# How to compute a prediction interval for an exponentially distributed random variable.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, mathematical-modeling, maximum-likelihood

I have fitted an exponential model to some data using maximum likelihood estimation and am now trying to compute a prediction interval for a new observation, $P$, which has a corresponding explanatory variable equal to $70$.

Under my model, $P \sim \text{Exp}(e^{\beta_1 + \beta_2 \times 70})$ and I have estimated $\hat{\beta}_1 = -4.317$ and $\hat{\beta}_2 = -0.028$. Further, the inverse observed fisher information for the model is:

$$-H(\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}})^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 0.615 & -0.009 \\ -0.009 & 0.00017 \end{bmatrix}$$

My question is, how can I create a $95\%$ prediction interval for $P$ using this information?

Comment: Your model form is very unclear from your question.  If you fit an exponential distribution to your data, this is a model with only one identifiable parameter, so how were you able to estimate two parameters?  Did you really use a scale parameter that is the *exponential* of a linear function of $x$, or is this a mistake?  Please specify your actual model form correctly so we can help answer your question.  (Also, your $\theta$ should be a $\beta$.)

Comment: Yes I fit an exponential model where the rate parameter is the exponential of a linear function of x. This ensures that the rate would always be positive and make sense.

Comment: In that case, how were you able to get estimates for both parameters?  If you are using an exponential model, the rate parameter is identifiable, but the separate coefficients in that linear function would not be identifiable.